# Load testing in Visual Studio. What is Error/sec attribute?

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, load-testing, stress-testing

Need some help.

I created a load test: 100 users per step, one step is 10 seconds.
Visual Studio produced excel result, and I can not undestand **Errors/sec** value in results.

**What is "LoadTest:Errors, Errors/Sec, _Total?"**
**How was this value calculated?**

In my report some of these values are not integer. Why?
Also, there are not integer values for attribute "LoadTest:Errors, Threshold Violations/Sec, _Total".

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each request that fails, each extraction or validation rule that fails, etc, counts as one error. The whole load test runs for a period of time and during that time a number of errors are reported. The errors that occur during each sampling interval are counted and dividing those counts by the sampling period duration in seconds gives the number of errors per second. If the sampling interval is 30 seconds and during three intervals there are 45, 75 and 90 errors then these samples have 1.5, 2.5 and 3 errors per second, respectively.

The sampling interval is specified as a property of the "Run settings" of the load test. Microsoft provide [some guidance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff423846.aspx) on the values to use for different test durations. [This page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997552.aspx) introduces many other properties of the load test's "Run settings".

Comment: What is sampling interval? Is it step time?

Comment: @fr0ga See updated answer. The step time is entirely different.

Comment: Could you please explain one important thing for me? Example: there are 2 users in load test, they start request to web-service, one user recieved request result and one did not recieve. When the first user will start another request, immediately after recieving his response, on when the second user will recieve response too? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @fr0ga That new question appears to be unrelated to error counts. I suggest you ask a new question. The way you have written it in the above comment is not clear, so you would need to be much clearer about what you are asking.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53323471/load-testing-in-visual-studio-how-number-of-simultaneous-users-is-implemented-i
You are welcome! :)