# Load testing in Visual Studio. How number of simultaneous users is implemented in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, load-testing, stress-testing

Could you please explain, how load or stress test is released inside Visual Studio when the test is oriented on the number of simultaneous users?

Example:

**Step user count:** 0

**Initial user count:** 2.

**Run duration and step duration:** does not important really because user count is always the same (2), let it be 30 seconds for run duration and 30 seconds for step duration. It is a kind bit weird configuration for the test but it helps to show the main idea of my question.
Web serivce is able to response after small period of time (0.1-0.5 sec).

There are 2 users in load test, they start request to web-service, one user recieved request result and one did not recieve. When the first user will start another request, **1)** immediately after recieving his response, **2)** or when the second user will recieve response too? Am I right that users' requests start absolutely idependently, one user is able to recieve 30/0.1=300 responses and the second one is able to recieve 30/0.5=60 responses after the test? Users send the same requests to the same service.

In these **2** scenarious could be different number of errors that will be recieved during this small test. For me, it is important to understand after what period of time (or event) the next request will begin for the same user?

Thank you.

Comment: You question is hard to understand. I think the second paragraph of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48987341/546871) may give the information you want. If not then please consider rewording it.

Comment: I should have written: ... If not then please consider rewording your question.